# JSF 1.2 - getClientId returns ID begining with "null" instead of container list followed by ID

Tags: java, jsp, jsf-1.2, myfaces, trinidad

Our application is using JSF 1.2 implemented by MyFaces 1.2.9 and Trinidad 1.2.14 running on Weblogic Portal 10.3.2, JDK 1.6_22.  We are seeing an issue in the rendered html pages delivered to the browser when the system gets under heavy load (the load is simulated with HP LoadRunner and simulates 800 concurrent users).

We are seeing the generated id's used for tag id's and in javascript losing the parent container names and instead coming with null followed by the field id.

Our JSP files are laid out as such:

**homemenu.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad" prefix="tr" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html" prefix="trh" %>
<f:view>
    <f:subview id="renderBody">
        <jsp:include page="../tabMenu.jsp" />  
    </f:subview>
...
```

**tabMenu.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad" prefix="tr" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html" prefix="trh" %>

<f:view>
     <f:subview id="tabmenu">  
        <jsp:include page="portalTemplate.jsp" />  
     </f:subview>
...
```

The generated HTML would contain code as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.faces.FORM" value="renderBody:tabmenu:j_id_id2pc3">
```

The value  attribute contains the correct container ID's, in this case renderBody:tabmenu

After the system has been under load for a while (about 30 - 45 minutes with about 800 concurrent users/sessions) the generated HTML will lose the container ID's.

```
<input type="hidden" name="org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.faces.FORM" value="null:j_id_id2pc3">
```

The value, which used to have renderBody:tabmenu as its parent ID, now instead has null.

Now this isn't causing issues with the functionality of the application, however it is causing issues with our LoanRunner test.  LoadRunner is looking for the full ID, and when the system starts generating them as null, this causes the LoanRunner tests to fail and error out.

What could be causing the Generated ID's to lose their parent ID's?  And why are we only seeing this when the system is under load?  Once the system starts generating null, it will continue to generate null, even when under no load, until the application is restarted.

We have tried setting the system property org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.CLIENT_ID_CACHING=off hoping this was a caching issue, but it has had no affect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked the developer of this section of code?